# Unable to start debugging IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 500.19

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

I tried to run my WebApp on my local machine today (nothing has changed on it) and I had the above error. I know my machine had a windows update recently (not sure if that has anything to do with it).

The error produces a big print out of css styles and html markup.

In the markup it also says "The requested page cannot be accecssed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you accidentally changed the web.config and now contains a malformed section. I'd recommend you take a close look to your configuration file.

I'd say that the error page should tell you the necessary information to solve the problem but I assume that if you're asking if because it's not the case :)

Comment: yes, one slight problem is the output is in a popup window which consumes my whole screen and I can't scroll down to read the bottom as there is no scroller.

Comment: @Dkong: Do you have this same limitation on all browsers?

Comment: Claudio, thanks for your suggestion. I tried it in FireFox and was able to read the message. Now that I can see the error I still can't fix it. It says:

"Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'ScriptModule' "  

and references

 <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" preCondition="managedHandler"/>

Comment: @Dkong: if you search for that entry on the web.config is only present 1 time?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the user info. (windows password which was changed) in the IIS & that helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable windows (or some other type of) authentication in IIS for the site specifically.